# Prove that $Q_8$ has a subgroup $H$ of order $2$ and $H$ is normal in $Q_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Prove that $Q_8$ has a subgroup $H$ of order $2$ and $H$ is normal in $Q_8$

Attempt

We have Quantemion group $Q_8=\{\pm 1, \pm i, \pm j,\pm k\}$. Its subgroups are $\{1\}, \{-1,1\}, \{-1,1,-i,i\}, \{-1,1,-j,j\}, \{-1,1,-k,k\}$, and $\{-1,1,-i,i,-j,j,-k,k\}$ of which $H=\{-1,1\}$ is a subgroup of order 2.

Question:
1. Is there any other subgroup of order 2.
2. How to show that this subgroup of order 2 is normal in $Q_8$?

Please help.

Comment: There is only one subgroup of order $2$, see [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_quaternion_group).

Comment: @DietrichBurde How to show that it is normal?

Comment: Because it is equal to the group center - see the duplicate above.

Comment: How to show that "it is equal to the group center"

Comment: Only $\pm 1$ commute with $i,j,k$. See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1779530/let-q8-represent-the-group-of-quaternions-and-v4%E2%88%BC-z-2z-%E2%8A%95-z-2z-represent-the-kle), where Johannes Huisman computes the center of $Q_8$.